# Transitioning colors in YUI?

Tags: javascript, yui, yahoo

I'm trying to transition color with a delay for something I'm coding in YUI, the problem is for some reason, IE will not transition the color . . . everything else transitions fine in IE but the color remains transparent.

I think it's easier to just post some example code as opposed to trying to explain what is going on:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sb3Gt/

Check this in Firefox/Chrome and you should see the color turn from transparent to black after a short delay, then check it in IE and the color stays transparent.

Is this a known issue with YUI or have I made a mistake in my JavaScript?

**EDIT: For the example to work you have to click the grey square.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was an issue with YUI, for more information see [here](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=92&t=10489)